# Magento - To print out the username along with comment

Tags: magento

Iam trying to add the admin user's name along with the comment in the magento sales_order_view_history block in adminhtml.
I have created a new .phtml which will echo out the username as well along with the comment. But on clicking the submit comment button , it is again calling the old .phtml file. Any idea why is it happening so?

Answer (score 0):

Please do cache disable and re-index data in admin.

```
System->Cache Management

 - select all and disable cache.

System->Index Management

 - select all and Reindex Data.
```

Please try this. May be help to you.